# Using an HLookup to susbstitiute for a column in an INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to use and HLOOKUP to INDEX a variable column in a date/dollars report. Please look at my data and the formulas I have written.

The goal is to have a date in Q6 that will return the person's $'s spent in that month.

Here is the data and formulas I am using...

Fixed Value of Column to return "1-Dec-16" (Q6)

Row to Return   "Billy" (Q8)

```
HLOOKUP(Q6,B1:O1,1) = 1-Dec-16

INDEX(M:M,MATCH(Q8,A:A,FALSE),1)  = 12
```

Combining them (replacing the specific M:M callout) gives me a REF error

```
INDEX(HLOOKUP(Q6,B1:O1,1),MATCH(Q8,A:A,FALSE),1) = #REF!
```

Can anyone explain why this error is occurring or perhaps help me tweak the code to get the formula working. I appreciate any assistance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the HLOOKUP just gives a single value, but you need a whole column to go in the first part of the INDEX statement.

You could get the column by using index-match on the two-dimensional array A:O

```
INDEX(A:O,,MATCH(Q6,1:1,0))
```

and then use this in another index-match

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A:O,,MATCH(Q6,1:1,0)),MATCH(Q8,A:A,0))
```

but I think it's easier to find the row and column with MATCH statements and use just one INDEX to find the cell you want:-

```
=INDEX(A:O,MATCH(Q8,A:A,0),MATCH(Q6,1:1,0))
```